# exterior to interior outlet

Tags: electrical

i am looking for a wall outlet the will alow me to plug in to it form out side and to plug into it on the inside of the house. need one side to be female and the other male.  anyone seen one of these or heard of them? looking to be able to get one from a big box or even a small box store. only one i have found online so far is from a site that i have never heard of and seams quite over priced at 90.00 bucks

Comment: You're wanting to add an outlet on the inside of your house from an exterior outlet?

Comment: Are you really looking for a generator inlet box?

Comment: What are you trying to power this rig from?

Answer (score 2):

It's called an **inlet**.  They don't need to cost $90 (unless you really want them to). They are odd, but I would still expect to find a NEMA 5-15 inlet in the $15-25 range.

*Keep in mind electrical parts don't lend themselves to online sale, because they are low in value, common as dirt, and heavy of weight.  Your best prices for anything slightly oddball will be at whichever electrical supply house doesn't mind giving you trade prices*.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a totally X-Y problem (i.e. focusing on one solution when some other solution would be much better).

The type of wall transition device that you are envisioning would only be good for extending some inside extension cord to the outside where you would plug in some other extension cord. Daisy chaining extension cords is not the best course of action.

It would far preferable if you located the outside electrical box in the same stud cavity as an internal outlet electrical box. Then extend a new cable from the internal box into the new exterior box and connect the ends of it to a new standard outlet of high quality. That outlet should probably be a GFCI type with an environmental type cover.